# ThreadLocal and await

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await

We have a logging system where we use `Log.Info` and it writes to an `ILogger`.

Now we have multiple workers running in the background, and we want these to write to their own logs. So everything is bundled per Worker. Everything that is logged when this task is being executed should be forwarded to its own logger.

We were thinking about making a method Log.SetLoggerForCurrentThread, implementing it with ThreadLocal. The executing code would look something like this:

```
public class Worker
{
    ILogger _Logger;

    public void ExecuteTask()
    {
        Log.Info( "This goes to the 'Global' logger" );

        using ( Log.SetLoggerForCurrentThread(_Logger) )
        {
             Log.Info( "This goes to local logger" );
             DoWork();
        }
    }

    private async void DoWork()
    {
        Log.Info( "Starting..." );

        // SomeMethod does some logging, 
        // that also needs to be forwared to the local logger
        var value = await SomeDeepDomainClass.SomeMethod();

        // if we use ThreadLocal, and this thread has been reused, 
        // it could be a completely different logger that is now attached.
        Log.Info( "Ended..." );
    }
}
```

**Questions**

- When we use await, the thread could in theory process work on another worker, thus mixing up the local loggers.
- What is the best pattern to do something similar? What storage method can I use?
- How does `CultureInfo` handle this?

**Background information**

Most of these Workers will run within an Azure WorkerRole instance, but now and then they are also triggered (once) from a Console application.

Comment: `CultureInfo` is set up at the start of each managed thread--that's independent of `Task`.  I would recommend the explicit use of `Log.SetLoggerForCurrentThread` if you want to log from a `Task`.  It shows you've explicitly thought of this and compensated.

Comment: Before I start working on an answer, you should know that log4net is free and solves most of your problems already.

Comment: Hi @GuillaumeCR, you might be right, but see it as a general programming question for similar patterns.

Comment: Hi @PeterRitchie, what storage should I use for SetLoggerForCurrentThread if I can't use ThreadLocal?

Comment: @DirkBoer, my comment came about because I missed the `Log.SetLoggerForCurrentThread` line. I've now removed it because the question is, indeed, clear in that respect. What will make it better though is if you mention the technology that you're working with (WinForms/WPF/Console project/ASP.NET/Class Library), as there are differences in how `SynchronizationContext` is captured and posted back to in different cases (although the very fact that you're having to worry about this *just* to get your logging to work should probably be a pretty strong indicator that your design needs work).

Comment: Hi @KirillShlenskiy, the workers are mostly running all within a WorkerRole Azure instance. The logging works fine on itself. I just want to go the extra step and keep the logs from every worker grouped. So I can see when SomeDeepDomainMethod() is called from WorkerA, or WorkerB.

Comment: Why can't you use thread-local storage?

Comment: @PeterRitchie, 5 seconds after the code is finished a junior programmer will jump in and put in a bunch of `ConfigureAwait(false)` on all awaited tasks (or even just a couple of them - should be enough to bring down the entire logging ecosystem if the loggers are thread-local).

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy no point in writing any code if you hire people that are just going to break it every 5 seconds.

Comment: I'm struggling to write a good answer. Basically if your problem is logging, log4net is the answer. If your problem is synchronizing messaging between threads then the answer is a proper messaging framework, e.g. RabbitMQ. Parallelism works best when following the map/reduce pattern, and sharing data between threads is just a recipe for disaster.

Comment: @PeterRitchie, we had this exact discussion about a week ago, but both of our opinions were the polar opposites of what they are in this instance. My view was "this is carefully crafted to get the job done, but you have to pay attention", yours: "it's likely it will break down the track, therefore it's bad" (wording not exact and no malice intended). Funny.

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy I used to have that point of view (defensive design/programming for less-than-average programmers).  But it's a no-win situation.  It's a product, not a learning platform.  If programmers keep breaking it, teach them in other ways.  If that doesn't work, get rid of them.

Comment: The value-add from async/await goes down significantly when you use it in code that runs on a worker thread.  Which is already runs asynchronously, using await only adds overhead.  And problems like this, it *will* go wrong since the continuation runs on another thread.  This is not for free.  Do keep in mind that CultureInfo doesn't flow either, a notorious problem in .NET.

Comment: Hi @HansPassant, if your worker is downloading a big xml file from some site, aren't you really wasting a thread that is just waiting for that file to be downloaded?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use CallContext to pass (serializable) data across threads. See this article for an example:
https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/implicit-async-context-asynclocal.html

For some background information, see this article:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/executioncontext-vs-synchronizationcontext/

Comment: You should post a meaningful code example of your answer. Dont relay on external links which may die.

Answer (score 6):

In my opinion, the best solution is to either pass the logger instances as arguments (or member variables), or inject them (e.g., using nested scopes).

However, if you want to store and pass the logging instance implicitly in a way that is compatible with `await`, then you'll need to use the logical call context. I have a [blog post describing this approach](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/04/implicit-async-context-asynclocal.html), which points out the limitations of this approach:

1. It only works on the full .NET 4.5 framework.
2. You must use "overwrite" semantics. This generally means storing only immutable data.

With this in mind, here's some code that should work for your needs:

```
public static class LocalLogger
{
  private static readonly string name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");

  // Static Log methods should read this.
  public static ILogger CurrentLogger
  {
    public get
    {
      var ret = CallContext.LogicalGetData(name) as ILogger;
      return ret == null ? Logger.GlobalLogger : ret;
    }

    private set
    {
      CallContext.LogicalSetData(name, value);
    }
  }

  // Client code uses this.
  public static IDisposable UseLogger(ILogger logger)
  {
    var oldLogger = CurrentLogger;
    CurrentLogger = logger;
    if (oldLogger == GlobalLogger)
      return NoopDisposable.Instance;
    return new SetWhenDisposed(oldLogger);
  }

  private sealed class NoopDisposable : IDisposable
  {
    public void Dispose() { }
    public static readonly Instance = new NoopDisposable();
  }

  private sealed class SetWhenDisposed : IDisposable
  {
    private readonly ILogger _oldLogger;
    private bool _disposed;

    public SetWhenDisposed(ILogger oldLogger)
    {
      _oldLogger = oldLogger;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
      if (_disposed)
        return;
      CurrentLogger = _oldLogger;
      _disposed = true;
    }
  }
}
```